# Devexpress mvc gridview group datetime column by date?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I have datetime column in gridview:

```
settings.Columns.Add(clmn =>
{
     clmn.FieldName = "InsertDate";
     clmn.Caption = TsmDxWeb.Resources.InsertDate;
     clmn.CellStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.False;
     clmn.Width = 150;
     clmn.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending;
});
```

output:

[image]

and group output:

[image]

grid group data by datetime, but I want to group them by only date.

If I add `clmn.Settings.GroupInterval = DevExpress.XtraGrid.ColumnGroupInterval.Date;`, no data shown in grouping. Because gridview add time '00.00.000' to dates.

Also, there is a gridviewSetting that named `setting.CustomColumnGroup`, but there is no example. I researched a lot for an example but, I could not find anything.

How can I group records only by date without time?

Answer (score 0):

```
settings.Columns.Add(clmn =>
{
     clmn.FieldName = "InsertDate";
     clmn.Caption = TsmDxWeb.Resources.InsertDate;
     clmn.CellStyle.Wrap = DefaultBoolean.False;
     clmn.Width = 150;
     clmn.SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending;
     clmn.Settings.GroupInterval = DevExpress.XtraGrid.ColumnGroupInterval.Date;
});
```

"Rows are grouped by the date part of their values, the time portion is ignored"

Comment: In my question, I m talking about `ColumnGroupInterval` . And this does not work...